# How to determine at runtime when your C++ application has the visual studio debugger attached?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

How do you determine at runtime whether the visual studio debugger is attached to your process. I've seen instructions for how to do this in .NET, but my process is a native C++ process. Support for detecting Just-in-time debugging would be nice but not a strict requirement.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to detect if the debugger is attached from within the process the debugger is attached to, or from a different outside process?

Comment: from inside the process the debugger is attached to. IsDebuggerPresent worked as suggested below.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101806/check-if-application-was-started-from-within-visual-studio

Comment: not really a dupe (although the IsDebuggerPresent function was mentioned) - that question was for .net specifically. This is for C++/Win32.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Win32 call `IsDebuggerPresent()` sounds like it ought to work.

Comment: I used this approach but then saw the blog in the following link where he claims he dissabled IsDebuggerPresent through a script, so this approach can be problematic:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2007/05/23/windbg-script-disabling-isdebuggerpresent/

Answer (score 4):

Use [IsDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: +1 for being the right answer, even if 2 minutes later than unwind's answer. Thanks to you also.