# Convert Hex to Double to Hex?

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, hex, double

In my project I have a QString with the hex value (Big Endian)

```
QString hex_in("413DF3EBA463B0");
```

How could I convert hex_in to a rounded double? IEEE 754 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

```
34.5
```

The user will edit the double and then my program needs to convert it back to hex.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: How are hex string and double related? Is the string a representation of the binary memory layout of the double? What encoding? IEEE?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, IEEE 754. The string is a hexadecimal representation of the double.

Comment: Big Endian or Little Endian?

Comment: Actually. I really apologize for this, it is Big Endian.

Comment: "413DF3EBA463B0" only has 14 characters. You need another two for the internal representation of a double. Which end?

Comment: This hex value is ripped straight from a game, so as for your question, idk the answer :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really only one way to do it, and that is to convert the string to an integer, put it in a `union` where you set an integer member and read out a `double` member.

For the string conversion you can use e.g. [one of these functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

---

Example code:

```
double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
    union
    {
        long long i;
        double    d;
    } value;

    value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);

    return value.d;
}

// ...

std::cout << "413DF3EBA463B0 = " << hexstr2double("413DF3EBA463B0") << '\n';
```

The output of the code above will be

```
413DF3EBA463B0 = 1.91824e-307
```

Comment: I'm not converting a string to a number, I want what the string represents, hex, to convert to a number. Unless I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @mc360pro But there is no way of knowing what number a string may represent, without converting the string *to* that number.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Convert this hex value into a number. Wouldn't converting JUST the string to a double convert the ascii characters or something and not what the actual hex values mean?

Comment: @mc360pro Instead of parsing each character, use the functionality already in the language and standard library. I've updated my answer with some very simple code.

Comment: Thanks for this :) However, is there anyway to get this as big endian?

Comment: @mc360pro Byte-swap the integer number. There are plenty of example on how to do it all over the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. I will mess with this and get back to you with an answer :)

Comment: @mc360pro [`htonll`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375340/c-htonll-and-back) will come in handy.

Comment: How can I go from double back to hex with this method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    double HexToDouble(AnsiString str)
{
  double hx ;
  int nn,r;
  char * ch = str.c_str();
  char * p,pp;
  for (int i = 1; i <= str.Length(); i++)
  {
    r = str.Length() - i;
    pp =   ch[r];
    nn = strtoul(&pp, &p, 16 );
    hx = hx + nn * pow(16 , i-1);
   }
  return hx;
}
```

my function for big hex digit

> result

```
72850ccbb88c6226afed9d8d971c8938        -->     1.5222282653101E+38     
000015d85a903c72b6bebdd18fb26811        -->     4.4307191280143E+32
```